# How can I delete a nested element from an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

assuming an interface such as:

```
interface CustomNode {
  id: string;
  children: CustomNode[];
}
```

If I have an object such as:

```
nodes: CustomNode[] = [
  {
     id: 'A',
     children: [
       {
         id: 'B',
         children: [
           {
             id: 'C',
             children: [
               {
                 id: 'D',
                 children: []
               },
               {
                 id: 'E',
                 children: []
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

how could I create a function that removes a given 'CustomNode' and its children?

I prefer a Typescript/ES6 solution, but am okay with any general solution (e.g. Typescript, Javascript, ES, dependencies such as lodash, etc)

**e.g. How can I remove CustomNode with ID 'C' and its children?**

```
nodes = removeIfExists(nodes, 'C');
```

```
removeIfExists(nodes: CustomNode[], removeId: string) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify your existing data or return a copy of it?

Comment: @jcalz either way is fine. I'd prefer to return a copy but if its easier to modify the existing data, that's fine too.

Comment: did you try iteration?? I know it's not the most efficient solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to mutate the existing array or any of its nodes, and also assuming that you are operating on an array of nodes and not one node (it looks like that's what you want),  you could write it like this:

```
function removeIfExists(nodes: CustomNode[], removeId: string): CustomNode[] {
    return nodes.
        filter(n => n.id !== removeId).
        map(n => ({ id: n.id, children: removeIfExists(n.children, removeId) }));
}
```

We're removing all entries with the offending id, and then mapping the remaining nodes recursively.  Let's make sure it works on your example (which I've renamed `nodes`):

```
const newNodes = removeIfExists(nodes, "C");
console.log(JSON.stringify(newNodes));
//[{ "id": "A", "children": [{ "id": "B", "children": [] }] }]
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAORwBMUBvAWAChlblhiAuZbKUAcwG5q7kEALYABtiUCCGYZs+IqQDaAXW5UAvtWoIcIbMhAkImSVlyF9i5AF5kcnnUo1edBswDkAQRcAaW476CRYhLWPr52IaGOzsguAEJe4RF0AsKi4sw2DomJ9lm5TkzRqPGZeYnJAWnBJaW5OTX1tFEuACLFDQ3lqUGKCe2OKt7VfY51w7lNAKJtY7mdgekKvTNqQ32Lq6UrDet5W6E7dCtK6lQw6CAIYMBayGJ4OABuEACSMBMAHsDYmAAUeqSGNDGGRmBSeW4Qe5PZ4FVgcACURmkpnkCmQowhYHQUBAun0mAAdEsYMJIFA-pYAHy6AkMZAAQgsVjujxexHhRI2eDgAAcKRZqT8yPQCiBacRwXNKizoW9Pt8-gSpSBwTK2fDkCp4fDlCsTpptGBdBAAO6yAyWCFQl5yr5gX7-AzggBEqGdOo0WkwOCEEAJQhw7B+ACkAMoAeQIBLhIHYwBgAE8-qbzZhtcoAPQZuTC50MZ3MZ1uZ0u5UF6y5-OFmIl5DOssLTVolTrIA)

Answer (score 0):

An Example :

```
var array = [['firstItem','secondItem'],['thirdItem','fourthItem']];
array[0][1] = null;
```

```js
 array = [['firstItem','secondItem'],['thirdItem','lastItem']];
array[0][1] = null;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = array[0][1]
```

```html
<html>
<p id="demo"></p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new `CustomNode[]` the fastest way to do that is:

```js
function removeIfExists(nodes: CustomNode[], removeId: string): CustomNode[] {
    let res: CustomNode[] = [];
    for (const node of nodes) {
        if (node.id === removeId) {
            continue;
        }
        res.push({
            id: node.id,
            children: removeIfExists(node.children, removeId),
        })
    }
    return res;
}
```

If you want to modify the current object you can do:

```js
function removeIfExists(nodes: CustomNode[], removeId: string): CustomNode[] {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < nodes.length) {
        if (nodes[i].id === removeId) {
            nodes.splice(i, 1);
            continue;
        }
        removeIfExists(nodes[i].children, removeId);
        ++i;
    }
    return nodes;
}
```